# Css won't install font

Tags: css

I have used this to my CSS but the CSS font won't load.

```
@font-face {
font-family: Champagne;
src: url('css/font/Champagne_Limousines.TTF'); }
```

Comment: What is your directory structure?

Comment: Read my several updates times' post.

Comment: There are dozens of possible explanations, e.g. the font resource does not exist in the specified address, you are testing on a browser that does not support embedding of TTF fonts, you have no CSS rule that actually uses the font declared, etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that it's not usually enough to offer up just .ttf format. That won't work in some browsers. For a more bulletproof result, see the file types mentioned here: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/

There is a handy generator here fo getting the files you need: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator (or you may be happy with this ready-made version of Champagne: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/CAC-Champagne).

Of course, also make sure your file paths are correct. Your file path is telling the style sheet to look for a folder called `/css/` *inside the folder containing the style sheet*, which is most likely not what you intended. You are more likely to want—

```
src: url('font/Champagne_Limousines.TTF');
```

Likewise, given the code you posted, if you don't have a `/font/` folder inside your `/css/` folder, then your file path is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try using woff ir woff2 format. That helped me.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding Quotation marks like this:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: 'Champagne';
   src: url('css/font/Champagne_Limousines.TTF') format('trutype');
   font-weight: normal;
   font-style: normal;
}
```

IF your directory are like this:

**/** *Folder* **/** *WhatEverNameForIndex.html*

**/** *Folder* **/**

**/** *Folder* **/** *css* **/**

**/** *Folder* **/** *css* **/** *WhatEverName.css*

And you are importing the css with html Header which are in the main **/** *Folder* **/**

You have to write this way:

```
src: url('font/Champagne_Limousines.ttf') format('truetype');
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this...

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Champagne';
    src: url('css/font/Champagne_Limousines.TTF') format('truetype');
}
```